# Could not cast value of type '__NSCFData' (0x39490110) to 'NSString' (0x394990ac)

Tags: ios, swift, objectmapper

There is crash while the casting the `jsonstring` to `object` using objectMapper framework in the following part of the code but the way I have implemented is correct I guess.

> Could not cast value of type '__NSCFData' (0x39490110) to 'NSString' (0x394990ac)

Here is the code:

```
static func saveUserRefererInfo(userRefInfo : UserRefererInfo?)
{
    if userRefInfo != nil {
        let jsonText = Mapper().toJSONString(userRefInfo!, prettyPrint: true)!
        userDefaults.set(jsonText, forKey: SharedPreferenceHelper.USER_REFERER_INFO)
    } else {
        userDefaults.set(nil, forKey: SharedPreferenceHelper.USER_REFERER_INFO)
    }
}

static func getUserRefererInfo() -> UserRefererInfo?
{
    let userRefInfo = userDefaults.value(forKey: SharedPreferenceHelper.USER_REFERER_INFO)
    if userRefInfo != nil {
        return Mapper<UserRefererInfo>().map(JSONString: userRefInfo! as! String)
    }
    return nil
}
```

The crash is happening in this line of the code:

```
return Mapper<UserRefererInfo>().map(JSONString: userRefInfo! as! String)
```

Comment: That part `userRefInfo! as! String` seems to be the cause. Your code seems correct. I'd suggest to remove the values saved into `UserDefaults`, you might have saved at some point a `Data` object during your tries instead of a `String` one. And prefers to use `userDefaults.object(forKey:)` instead of `userDefaults.value(forKey:)`, `value(forKey:)` might not do what you want in other cases.

Comment: Casting cannot change the type of something. `userRefInfo` is not a string so you can’t cast it as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pretty clear: The type of `userRefInfo` is `(NS)Data`.

I don't know how `userRefInfo` is processed further but this is the usual way to get `Data` from `UserDefaults`.

```
if let userRefInfo = userDefaults.data(forKey: SharedPreferenceHelper.USER_REFERER_INFO)
    return Mapper<UserRefererInfo>().map(JSONString: userRefInfo)
}
```

**Never** `value(forKey:` and **never** `if foo != nil { ... foo! }`

Consider that `ObjectMapper` became obsolete in favor of `Codable` in Swift 4+

Comment: if I am trying to use the above mentioned solution it is showing error as could not cast the value of type data to string

Comment: Of course not because the saved data is **not** `String`. Make sure that the saved data is `String` and then read the data with `string(forKey`